# How to treat dataset with multiple responses

Tags: r, correspondence-analysis

I had a survey were participants were asked to select their top three priority crops and whether they apply pesticides and irrigate them. So I have others who have selected two crops others three and others one crop and information for each crop whether they use pesticides on them and irrigation. I am a beginner in R so I entered the data in CSV as follows

```
Farmer  CropPriority    Irrigate Pesticide  
F1  Corn            1       0   
F2  Wheat       0           0   
F2  Corn        1       0   
F2  Rice        1       1   
F3  Beans       1       1   
F3  Wheat       1       1   
F3  Corn        1       11
```

Am not sure how to proceed with other variables like age, sex, level of education etc. which format will be good so that i can proceed with analysis in R

I tried to have separate files one with the participants responses and another with their socio demo graphic information. But upon merging them in R and summarize the data for example how many males and females respondents participated I get double the number because of the multiple entries for the questions.